# Error: Plugin burzum/cakephp-bz-utils could not be found

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, composer-php, jwt

I'm using `cakephp 2.9` , I have installed the plugin `burzum/cakephp-bz-utils` using

`php composer.phar require burzum/cakephp-bz-utils @dev` and in bootstrap.php : `CakePlugin::load('burzum/cakephp-bz-utils');`
but I got an error

`Error: Plugin burzum/cakephp-bz-utils could not be found`

I check plugin folder and it didn't exist but it installed in vendors folder
Am I doing something wrong?
I've clear the cache and tried to use `CakePlugin::loadAll();` but none of them has succeed.

Comment: Try load('Burzum/Utils'), I'm not running any 2.x app locally anymore right now, so I can't test it.

Comment: @burzum the same error `Plugin Burzum/Utils could not be found` :(